# how to load a picture captured from camera in another activity on image view?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera, android-bitmap

I have two image buttons,one is for taking a photo from gallery and display it in another activity. This works fine. It displays the photo with high quality . But when i try to take a picture from camera and then that photo to be displayed in another activity,it shows an error. Here is my code
MainActivity.java:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
private static int SELECT_FILE = 1;
public static Uri selectedImageURI;

if (take_photo != null) {
        take_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CAMERA);

            }
        });
    }
    //to get the photo from gallery
    if (get_photo != null) {
        get_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i,SELECT_FILE);


}

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            selectedImageURI = data.getData();
            File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowPhotoActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("imagePath", imageFile.toString());
             startActivity(intent);}
        else if (requestCode != RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA){
                Uri selectImageURI = data.getData();
                File imgFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectImageURI));
                Intent i = new Intent(this,ShowPhotoActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("imagePath",imgFile.toString());
                startActivity(i);

            }
        } }}
        private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI){
            String result;
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI,null,null,null,null);
            if(cursor == null){
                result = contentURI.getPath();

            }else {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                result = cursor.getString(idx);
                cursor.close();
            }
        return result;
    }
```

showPhotoActivity.java:

```
String image_path = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imagePath"));

    if (showPhoto != null) {

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath());
        showPhoto.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
```

manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

logcat:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.gentaliu.photoeditor/com.example.gentaliu.photoeditor.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3840)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3883)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1426)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1477)
                                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:473)
                                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:426)
                                                                                  at com.example.ga.photoeditor.MainActivity.getRealPathFromURI(MainActivity.java:96)
                                                                                  at com.example.ga.photoeditor.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:69)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6320)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3836)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3883) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:165) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1426) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

09-16 00:46:51.149 27066-27066/com.example.ga.photoeditor I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27066 SIG: 9

Comment: Simply decode your path in your second activity.

Comment: Did you see the code ? Because I did that ,but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
private static int SELECT_FILE = 1;
public static Uri selectedImageURI;

if (take_photo != null) {
        take_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
        });
    }

    //to get the photo from gallery
    if (get_photo != null) {
        get_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i,SELECT_FILE);
       }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            selectedImageURI = data.getData();
            File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowPhotoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("imagePath", imageFile.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
            }

        else if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA){
            Bitmap bitmapImage = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
            Intent i= new Intent(this,ShowPhotoActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("bitmap", bitmapImage);
            startActivity(i);

 }else{
       //do something 
      }
 }

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI){
            String result;
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI,null,null,null,null);
            if(cursor == null){
                result = contentURI.getPath();

            }else {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                result = cursor.getString(idx);
                cursor.close();
            }
        return result;
    }
```

And retrieve the Bitmap Image of Camera in second Activity:

```
private void getData(){

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

 }
```

Comment: It's not working. Cannot resolve symbole "intent" in Bitmap bitmapImage = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data"); . The image view in the second activity is the same for both the gallery photo and camera picture. That's why i need to pass it like string,then to parse it to uri and then to decode to bitmap,because I'm applying some filters. Just look what I'm doing with gallery photo, I wanna do the same with camera photo.

Comment: use `Bitmap bitmapImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` because you Intent variable is `data`.

Comment: And how to retrieve the bitmap in the other activity without damaging my gallery picture code ?

Comment: Use parceableExtra `Bitmap bitImage=getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bitmap");`

Comment: Us e like this `Intent intent = getIntent();`
`Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");`

Comment: I guess you're not understanding what I'm asking. You're code maybe it's good just for camera,but it damages my "bitmap gallery" code.Look at my code again and answer again,if you know how to do it.